Wiremock admin api use on pcf multiple instance/containers
We have hosted Wiremock standalone on PCF and using admin api to add stub mappings dynamically. This works great when there is only single instance. However, when it is scaled up and admin mapping is used, the stubs are available only on one instance.
Is there a way I can replicate this on all instances?

This is tricky. It will probably require you to write some custom extension.
Here is the workaround I use.

In you CI/ local system, start a container with plain wiremock image.
Do your stubbing using admin api in the local instance.
Save stubbing, this will save all your stubs in /mappings folder.
Now create your own image with wiremock as base image and with all saved stubs under /mappings.
Now deploy your own image with preloaded stubs with PCF (or whichever platform you are using).

